# Перенос JS кода в отдельный файл и подключение его на странице

Tags: javascript, yii2, views

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос. Сейчас балуюсь с изучением Yii2 и JS в нём.

Во вьюхе написал JS скрипт, все работает отлично, но понимаю, что это неправильно и в будущем будет просто огромная каша и будет сложно разобраться.

Как вынести в отдельный файл все скрипты JS и потом подключить во вьюхи?

По идее, все скрипты должны храниться в папке js.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как тогда подключить их во вьюхе?

Пример кода вьюхи:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="touch">Нажми на меня</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="donttouch">Не нажми на меня</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#touch").click(function(event){
            alert("Ну и зачем нажал?");
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#donttouch").click(function(event){
                alert("Хоп хей, ла ла лей.");
            });

        });

        $("#1").mouseover(function(){ $("#1").css("color","red");});
        $("#1").mouseout(function(){ $("#1").css("color","black");});

    });
</script>
<br/><br/>
<p id="1">Довольно интересно все. Попробуй навести на меня</p>
```

Буду очень признателен за ответ и пояснение что к чему. С: Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле всё зависит...зависит, что это за скрипты и какую миссию они выполняют. Иногда нужно прямо в шаблоне написать несколько строк, а иногда лучше и вынести в отдельные файлы. Нужно смотреть по обстоятельствам, а не выстраивать всё всегда абсолютным образом.

---

**Сразу уточнение по...** ... по поводу *Jquery* и  *Bootstrap* - хочу напомнить, что по дефолту *Yii2* уже включает в себя эти скрипты и складывать новые не обязательно. Разве что настроить их самые новые версии в `config` приложения

---

В общем случае можно их добавлять в так называемые комплекты ресурсов. Самый простой пример — `AppAsset`, который лежит в папке `assets` прямо в корне (на том же уровне, что и web/config/models/controllers). В этом комплекте можно настроить данные по своему вкусу:

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle {
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

например `$js` содержит массив файлов `js`, которые будут подключены, если будет использоваться этот ресурс. `$depends` - зависимости от других комплектов. Например можно указать, что твой зависит от `BootstrapAsset` и тогда он будет подключаться на странице автоматически с твоим.

Если хочешь, можешь накидать список скриптов прямо в `AppAsset`,  а можешь разделить свои скрипты на группы и создать свой (свои) комплект по аналогии.

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;
use Yii;

class TestAsset extends AssetBundle {
    ...
    ...

    public $js = [
        'test.js' 
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

**(!!!)** При этом его надо не забыть зарегистрировать во view (например непосредственно в layout)

```
TestAsset::register($this);
```

Можешь открыть файл `views\layouts\main.php` - там должен быть пример.

Более подробно про комплекты ресурсов можно почитать **[в документации на русском](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-assets.md)** или **[английском](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html)**

---

Иногда можно во `view` подключать необходимые скрипты, без комплектов. Просто точечно и одноразово. В таком случае можешь воспользоваться

**[registerJs() и registerJsFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html)**

Comment: Спасибо за глубокий ответ. ) 
А то начал писать свой ответ, когда вы ответили.

Comment: @Anatoliy.CHA советую просто хотя бы мельком глаза посмотреть в гайд на русском https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru . всё запомнить невозможно, но иногда при возникновении вопросов в голове будет всплывать инфа, что такое где-то читал и останется только донайти

Comment: Возьму на заметку и буду использовать. 
Ещё раз спасибо. С:

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было сделать, как написал @Nikita, но не хватало лишь одного, прописать js файл в AppAsset.

1. Помещаешь свои скрипты в файла .js
2. прописываешь к нему путь во View
3. Добавляем файл в AppAsset.php